TypeError: clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fix_unicode'
I have write a python program into implement BERT algorithm But I encounter below error and cleantext() function is below.I updated cleantext package but it does not work.I have write a python program into implement BERT algorithm But I encounter below error and cleantext() function is below.I updated cleantext package but it does not work
code:
def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    return cleantext

def cleaning(text):
    text = text.strip()
    
    # regular cleaning
    text = clean(text,
        fix_unicode=True,
        to_ascii=False,
        lower=True,
        no_line_breaks=True,
        no_urls=True,
        no_emails=True,
        no_phone_numbers=True,
        no_numbers=False,
        no_digits=False,
        no_currency_symbols=True,
        no_punct=False,
        replace_with_url="",
        replace_with_email="",
        replace_with_phone_number="",
        replace_with_number="",
        replace_with_digit="0",
        replace_with_currency_symbol="",
    )

    # cleaning htmls
    text = cleanhtml(text)
    
    # normalizing
    normalizer = hazm.Normalizer()
    text = normalizer.normalize(text)
    # removing wierd patterns
    wierd_pattern = re.compile("["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
        u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937"
        u'\U00010000-\U0010ffff'
        u"\u200d"
        u"\u2640-\u2642"
        u"\u2600-\u2B55"
        u"\u23cf"
        u"\u23e9"
        u"\u231a"
        u"\u3030"
        u"\ufe0f"
        u"\u2069"
        u"\u2066"
        # u"\u200c"
        u"\u2068"
        u"\u2067"
        "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    
    text = wierd_pattern.sub(r'', text)
    
    # removing extra spaces, hashtags
    text = re.sub("#", "", text)
    text = re.sub("\s+", " ", text)
    
    return text

 data['cleaned_comment'] = data[2].apply(cleaning)

# calculate the length of comments based on their words
data['cleaned_comment_len_by_words'] = data['cleaned_comment'].apply(lambda t: len(hazm.word_tokenize(t)))

# remove comments with the length of fewer than three words
data['cleaned_comment_len_by_words'] = data['cleaned_comment_len_by_words'].apply(lambda len_t: len_t if minlim < len_t <= maxlim else len_t)
data = data.dropna(subset=['cleaned_comment_len_by_words'])
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

data.head()

Error :
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-17-46d1839b8806> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data['cleaned_comment'] = data[2].apply(cleaning)
      2 
      3 # calculate the length of comments based on their words
      4 data['cleaned_comment_len_by_words'] = data['cleaned_comment'].apply(lambda t: len(hazm.word_tokenize(t)))
      5 

4 frames

<ipython-input-12-1e73a60c1c12> in cleaning(text)
      8 
      9     # regular cleaning
---> 10     text = clean(text,
     11         fix_unicode=True,
     12         to_ascii=False,

TypeError: clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fix_unicode'

Please Help me to solve this problem

Please show your definition of the cleaning function

You have a function called cleaning that is calling another function called clean. That's where the problem is. You'll have to let us know what those things are. The code you show is only loosely related - you need to debug the cleaning function. Where does it get a clean function and do you have a version mismatch there?

I have updated the post with cleaning function

You call clean with a fix_unicode parameter, but clean doesn't have such a parameter. Look at the clean function to see what parameters it takes.
